# What is the most appropriate way to get Nautilus 3.8 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 13.04 comes with Nautilus 3.6 which disables expansion of folders in the listview mode. I've really tried this workflow for a good month or so - and it's not working for me. Nautilus authors mentioned that the abilisy to expand folders in treeview has been reinstated in 3.8.

What is the most appropriate way to obtain Nautilus 3.8 that'll be upgrade-proof and not so hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the easiest way to install Nautilus 3.8.x in Ubuntu 13.04**

- Add repository **Gnome3 PPA**:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
  ```
- Update Repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Now install  `Nautilus 3.8.2`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nautilus
  ```
- Check the nautilus version:

  ```
  nautilus --version
  ```

<sub>[Get the complete list of packages in gnome3 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=raring)</sub>

Comment: You linked to a slightly different PPA - archive vs gnome3 in the 'complete list' link.

Comment: That doesn't actually quite work:

````
$ nautilus
Could not register the application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gtk.Actions' on object at path /org/gnome/Nautilus
````

Hopefully installing the complete Gnome 3.8 will do it.

Comment: Actually there is a very long process to install `nautilus 3.8` by compiling it from binary process, that could be so tough.. Yes, you can install latest Gnome 3.8 from this repository and it will install `Nautilus 3.8` too.. If some packages are still missing you can add this repo: `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`. I want you to reply if all goes well.. Wish you all the best..